# Why does the xxd command not respect byte grouping when operated in reverse?

Tags: bash, xxd

I am trying to write bytes to a file on my system in a script, and I decided to use xxd (with -r) to achieve this. However, I want it to take endianness into account for each 4 bytes. here is an example i used to test this:

```
 echo "1122334455667788" | xxd -r -p -g 4  - outfile
```

I get the following output when i do `hexdump outfile`:

```
 0000000 2211 4433 6655 8877                    
 0000008
```

Because I used -g 4, I expect the result to be like this

```
 0000000 4433 2211 8877 6655                    
 0000008
```

It is not behaving like I expect it to. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I realise now that -g does is not supposed to change the byte ordering. However, xxd does take endianness into account as in the examples I provided. The question now is how can I get xxd to flip bytes in groups of 4 bytes (32-bit little endian values) instead of every 2 bytes to get the result I wanted? is this even possible with xxd alone?

Comment: Why should gouping change the order of elements. It works exactly as specified: `-g bytes - Separate the  output of every <bytes> bytes (two hex characters or eight bit-digits each) by a whitespace`

Comment: `xxd -h` says: `-g          number of octets per group in normal output. Default 2 (-e: 4).` maybe I misunderstood that. I can see that it is changing the byte order for every 2 bytes. Is there a way to make that 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `-g` option is meant to be used in the direct (not reverse) conversion and only to format the output as seen by an user:

```
$ printf '\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\n' 
 !"#$%&'

$ printf '\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\n' | xxd
00000000: 2021 2223 2425 2627 0a                    !"#$%&'.

$ printf '\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\n' | xxd -g 4
00000000: 20212223 24252627 0a                  !"#$%&'.
```

To get the presentation of byte values to change the order of Most Significant Bit you need a tool that actually could do the transformation:

```
printf '\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\n' | od -An -tx4 
 23222120 27262524 0000000a
```

And then use xxd to reverse those byte values to actual bytes:

```
printf '\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\n' | od -An -tx4 | xxd -r -p
#"! '&%$
```

Note that the order of the individual bytes has been reversed in each group of four bytes.

Comment: Marked as correct answer. I did something similar only using "fold -w 4 | tac". Thanks!